# Trouble with asList().contains() comparing variables

Tags: java, android, arrays, comparison

I'm making an app where the user has to choose a 4 digit number, and this will be compared to a randomly chosen hidden 4 digit number, but when ever I run the code which should check my array for a comparison between the chosen numbers and the random numbers the '**Arrays.asList().contains())**' doesn't seem to pickup on the fact that the array it is checking does have the value it is checking for, any advice?

The code that compares the two variables:-

```
            guess.v1 = code.int1;
            guess.v2 = code.int2;
            guess.v3 = code.int3;
            guess.v4 = code.int4;


       int[] guess_list = { guess.v1, guess.v2, guess.v3, guess.v4 };



    if (Arrays.asList(guess_list).contains(home.value1)) {
        if (code.int1 == home.value1) {
            X1.setText("V");

            guess.c1 = GuessStatus.V;
        } else {
            X1.setText("S");
            guess.c1 = GuessStatus.S;
        }
    } else {
        X1.setText("X");
        guess.c1 = GuessStatus.X;
    }
```

The code that generates the random numbers:-

```
                    Code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent openCode = new Intent(b, code.class);
            // adventure_time checks whether there is a saved game already,
            // if 1, saved game,
            adventure_time = 0;

            // random number generation LET THE NUMBER GAMES BEGIN///
            Random a1 = new Random();
            random1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            check.fudge = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
                random1.add(a1.nextInt(5) + 1);
                Log.v("MM", "" + random1.get(index));
            }

            value1 = random1.get(0);
            value2 = random1.get(1);
            value3 = random1.get(2);
            value4 = random1.get(3);
            startActivity(openCode);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling the `Arrays.asList` call you think you are. You're *actually* creating a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>` are you're probably expecting. (There's no such type as `List<int>` in Java, as it doesn't support generics over primitive types.)

The simplest fix would be to change this:

```
int[] guess_list = { guess.v1, guess.v2, guess.v3, guess.v4 };
```

to this:

```
Integer[] guess_list = { guess.v1, guess.v2, guess.v3, guess.v4 };
```

You'll then end up creating a `List<Integer>` which will work appropriately.